# Weighted covariance matrix using kernels

Tags: machine-learning, covariance, kernel-smoothing

I would like to create a weighted covariance matrix (say 5 variables) using 3 different time points where the weights come from a kernel function (can be normal, triangular, etc.) but I'm not understanding how it works. Basically I'm imagining

$$S(u,v)=\frac{w_1*cov_1(u,v)+w_2*cov_2(u,v)+w_3*cov_3(u,v)}{w_1+w_2+w_3},$$

where the numbers denote the 3 time points. Does that make sense?

Any method of combining the covariance estimates is a good start -- I'm completely open to alternative ideas! The kernel weights came from a paper by Razavian et al ["Time-Varying Gaussian Graphical Models of Molecular Dynamics Data"](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2059&context=compsci).

Here is some sample data:

```
cov1=matrix(c(175.28, 23.37, 12.76, 3.45, 5.94, 23.37, 90.29, 44.41, 42.83, 52.00, 12.76, 44.41, 29.94, 22.17, 22.39, 3.45, 42.83, 22.17, 31.95, 32.21, 5.94, 52.00, 22.39, 32.21, 58.22), 5, 5)
cov2=matrix(c(207.29, 43.96, 45.03, 35.60, 27.97, 43.96, 115.52, 71.71, 80.95, 68.69, 45.03, 71.71, 58.70, 53.07, 40.71, 35.60, 80.95, 53.07, 67.84, 51.95, 27.97, 68.69, 40.71, 51.95, 59.26), 5, 5)
cov3=matrix(c(165.67, 63.42, 37.82, 32.63, 43.37, 63.42, 121.70, 66.00, 74.47, 71.16, 37.82, 66.00, 47.34, 42.24, 34.40, 32.63, 74.47, 42.24, 55.98, 47.48, 43.37, 71.16, 34.40, 47.48, 75.61), 5, 5)
```

I've also plotted the normal, uniform, Epanechnikov, and triangular kernels but how do I know where in the plots do I get the "weights" for a specific covariance element? I've spent time reading about kernels and staring at these plots but... nothing.

```
f.normal <- function(x) { dnorm(x); }
f.uniform <- function(x) { ifelse(abs(x)<1, 0.5, 0); }
f.epanechnikov <- function(x) { ifelse(abs(x)<1, (1-x^2)*3/4, 0); }
f.triangle <- function(x) { ifelse(abs(x)<1, 1-abs(x), 0); }
plot(c(-1,1),c(0,1.2),xlab="z", ylab="", main="Kernels", type="n")
curve(f.normal(x), c(-1,1), add=T, lwd=2, lty=1, col="black")
curve(f.uniform(x), c(-1,1), add=T, lwd=2, lty=2, col="blue")
curve(f.epanechnikov(x), c(-1,1), add=T, lwd=2, lty=3, col="red")
curve(f.triangle(x), c(-1,1), add=T, lwd=2, lty=4, col="green")
legend(0.5,1.1,legend=c("Normal","Uniform","Epanech","Triangle"), lwd=c(2,2,2,2), lty=c(1,2,3,4), col=c("black","blue","red","green"),cex=0.8)
```

Any help please? Please be nice -- I really have been trying hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: You need to tell us, please, why you feel you need to weight covariances in the first place.

Comment: This is actually a precursor to analyzing these covariance estimates through graphical models (inverse covariance elements). Because I have 3 timepoints, one of the initial proposals was to somehow combine the covariance estimates through weights and then use this new weighted covariance to create a graphical model.

Comment: It seems any answer must depend on the missing information lying behind your "somehow." Can't you give us more to go on  than that?  What criteria can we apply to determine these weights and/or the method of combining the covariance estimates?

Comment: Sorry, the "somehow" is because of my lack of knowledge of what's going on. Any method of combining the covariance estimates is a good start -- I'm completely open to alternative ideas! The kernel weights came from a paper by Razavian et al ("Time-Varying Gaussian Graphical Models of Molecular Dynamics Data")

Comment: That's the first clue you have provided as to what you want to do--a reference to that paper belongs in the question itself.  Do you have a link to a public copy of the paper?

Comment: Here's a link: http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2059&context=compsci (the kernel part starts on the bottom of p.5). By the way, thank you @whuber for being patient with me. Even if we don't figure it out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I removed the "sum" from your equation for $S$ because it didn't make sense in the context. If that was wrong, please fix it up.